# Magento: Information about product pictures (small, thumb and so on), where in the DB?

Tags: database, magento, magento-1.4

I am trying to find the place in the Magento DB where it saves the information about what picture is thumb and small version etc. I checked catalog_product_entity_media_gallery, catalog_product_entity, catalog_product_entity_varchar and catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value, its not in those tables. Any ideas? I have a Magento 1.4 DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Magento save the thumb,small_image and large image name in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.

Since Magento is using the eav architecture, the thumbnail,small_image and large image is stored in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` with the reference ids from the `eav_attribute` table.

In `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table, `entity_id` represents the product id and the `attribute_id` represents the reference id from the attribute table.

Generally the attribute id 74 - `image`, 75- `small_image` and 76- `thumbnail`. You can check the corresponding id in the `eav_attribute` table.

For example, if a product with entity_id 1,

If we check the value for the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table, the value with respect to the attribute id 74 represents its image, 75 represents its small image and 76 represents its thumbnail..

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

The values belong to `catalog_product` attributes and will therefore be stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply **products_temp** table where you can check all products images path